# UITableView Parallax header to show multiple images

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, parallax, sticky

So there's an application called **RadPad** where they are able to do a sticky parallax table view header but at the same time have the ability to swipe horizontally to switch between images. I am wondering of what is the best way to achieve both features: being able to perform a parallax sticky header and show multiple images by using a UICollectionView.

I have tried various open source frameworks but they have not been successful in performing the stretchy header view when being pulled down further.

Thanks!

Below are links to the screens that I'm referring to:

1) Parallax: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybwog86zlvnd0p0/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-26%20at%2012.55.24%20PM.png?dl=0

2) Swiping between pictures horizontally: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i0sh23rhpcnf1m/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-26%20at%2012.56.03%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with the same problem and solution was to use `UITableView` and embed `UIPageViewController` as subview (because `UICollectionView` has problems with resizing cells). `UIPageViewController` should be resized at 'scrollViewDidScroll' to be stretchy. I've implemented sample project and shared it at [github](https://github.com/Erumaru/ios-table-view-stretchy-header).